# How ASP.NET MVC stores user information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

I am new to MVC, Have created simple application (very basic, only 1 controller) & used Entity Framework as ORM.

There is form for Registration in application, when I fill up that form user is registered & able to login with those credentials.

But there is no table created in my Database, so my question is where this registration information is stored?

I know this need knowledge of May be Membership/forms authentication, but I don't know them also.

I tried to search google for this, but may be I am not able to predict what to search.

**EDIT :**

Following is tag of DefaultConnection

Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AKShop-20140808100025.mdf

Comment: I believe by default MVC's registration uses the aspnet membership providers. I don't rate this framework very highly myself. I prefer to create the tables/authentication myself and use Forms/Claims authentication

Comment: where does aspnet membership providers stores information?\

Comment: take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Liath, thanks I have gone through this link, Edited my question & Added web.config tag for DefaultConnection, will I have mdf called aspnet-AKShop-20140808100025 on machine?

Comment: @AK47: Yes, you should. It depends on Data Source value in this connection string. Is it point to LocalDB or .\SQLExpress? If so, your DB is on your PC.

Comment: Which location is DataDirectory?

Comment: @AK47 This is shortcut. And by default it refers to App_Data folder in your project's folder. (That i've mentioned earlier)

Comment: @AK47 Please check YourProject/App_Data folder from Explorer but not from VS and check if this folder is empty.

Comment: Yes, folder is Empty! @ntl I searched for aspnet-AKShop-20140808100025.mdf on my machine but diden't found any results.

Comment: @AK47 Hm, strange. Please, check in this way: var dataLocation = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");

Answer (score 0):

I think that standard DB was created for your membership. Probably at app_data\aspnetdb.mdf.

Comment: There is no DB in App_Data.

Comment: In this case, please check you web.config for a connection strings (configuration/connectionStrings). What connections do you have? Because by default DB are created in Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; which points to App_Data in your project.

Comment: yep, added in my question, pls take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Before MVC 5, MembershipProvider or SimpleMembershipProvider by default, and data is persisted in (local) SQL server.

In MVC5, ASP.NET Identity 2.0 by default, and the data is persisted through Entity Framework which by default point to MS SQL, though it is easy to switch the persistence to other DB engines.

Identity 2.0 is quite new, and the official release is April this year, so this is why you got mixed info when searching the Internet. Nevertheless, if you have a green field MVC project, it might be better of to use MVC 5 and Identity 2.0.